# how to restart a spring batch chunck oriented at the correct position?

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, restart, chunks

Bonjour à tous,
I have a spring batch job where once of its steps is chunk-oriented with a size of 1 by iteration.
Its process is really simple.
- itemReader read a file and return a line
- itemProcess transform this line in object
- itemWriter persist this object in db.

Now I have wrote a unit test where I have volontary set a unparseable value to fail the job at the second iteration of this chunk so read 1 line and persist.

Now I use the jobId to restart it but I can see in the log that the step restart from the beginning and persist a second time the first line.

Do I need to skip it myself in the before step or do I need to set a specific annotation to restart from the correct chunk iteration?

regards,Mathieu

Comment: Are you sharing the same data source between the first run and the second run? The `FlatFileItemReader` stores a key named `read.count` in the execution context that is used in a restart scenario to resume reading from the last save point. Either make sure  you are using the same data source between your test runs or add this key manually to the execution context in your unit test.

Comment: Hi, yes i use the same database but i directly use itemreader, i'll try to use FlatFileItemReader